# how to navigate to some other view when user clicks Return key in Iphone?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am using IOS 5.0 and ,I am developing simple application in that I am using UITextFiled how to navigate to some other view when user clicks Return key from the Keypad.If anyone know help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
{
  // do something (like pushing a new view) 
  //when the user hits <enter> in the text field
}
```

then use these lines...

```
[myTextField setTarget:self];
[myTextField setAction:@selector(someAction:)];
```

Comment: for more information....
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW5

Comment: In modern XCode, the NSTextField can have different action modes. By default, an NSTextField is set to "Send on End Editing", which sends the action whenever you stop editing it for any reason (for example, tabbing away). But you can switch it in Interface Builder to "Send on Enter Only" (on the attributes tab, toward the bottom of the "Text Field" group of attributes), to make it only send the action when the user actually presses enter.